Не могу подтвердить мобильный в аккаунте разработчика в google play console
Столкнулся с такой проблемой что не могу подтвердить мобильный в аккаунте разработчика в google play console. Какой бы номер не писал, по звонку по смс, впин кеши все перепробовал - пишет Не удалось подтвердить номер телефона. Попробуйте изменить способ проверки.
В запросе ответ от их сервера {"1":8,"2":"Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)."}
Что делать? Тех поддержка мертвое дело

столкнулся с той же проблемой, сам из Беларуси.
польские номера тоже не работают.
работают российские номера оператора Теле2.
я все еще воюю с тех.поддержкой гугла (уже 2ой месяц пошел), но скорее всего решения не будет.
